# What is the best way of reading multiple lines to create one?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, chunks

I'm trying to calculate multiple things based on a group of lines (from a Db or a CSV it doesn't really matter).
For instance : I have 100 lines, each line has a **Delay** field and I want to get the **averageDelay** of these 100 lines to create ONE line with this value and other stuff from those 100 lines (occurence of delay greater than a certain amount of time for instance).

I'm knew to spring and spring-batch, that's why I need some advice on the best way of doing it wihtout writting some dirty code. I know that spring can be really powerfull but I'm missing some mechanics here.

My code is mostly based on this [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-batch-tasklet-chunk) (the one using chunks)
But I'm only looking for a good structure to begin with !

Let's say I have a class **InitialLine** :

```
public class InitialLine{

    private String feedID;
    private LocalDate dateTime;
    private Integer delay;


    /* Proper getters and setters here */

}
```

And an **finalLine** :

```
public class finalLine implements Serializable{

    private String feedId;
    private LocalDate dateTime;
    private Float averageDelay;
    // Delay greater than 100 second
    private Integer delayGT100;
    // Delay greater than 200 second
    private Integer delayGT200;

    /* Proper getters and setters here */

}
```

Will my *ItemReader* look something like this :

```
public class initialLineReader extends ItemReader<List<InitialLine>>{

    /* Declaration here*/

    private FilesUtils fu;

    @Override
    public List<InitialLine> read(){
        List<InitialLine> lines = fu.readInitialLines();
         return listFlux;
    }

    /* Other stuff*/

}
```

With **FileUtils** working this way :

```
public class FilesUtils {

    /* Declaration here */

    /* Here we are using a CSV file but it will be connected to DB after*/
    public List<InitialLine> readInitialLines() {
        try {
            if (CSVReader == null) initReader();


            // What should I put here ? 
            // Read every line with .readNext() and stacking it inside a List<InitialLine> ?


            String[] line = CSVReader.readNext();
            if (line == null) return null;
            return new LineFluxCapacity();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error while reading line in file: " + this.fileName);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /* Other stuff here*/
}
```

I think that usually chunks work like this :
- Reader : Read *ONE* item 
- Processor : Transform *ONE* item into *ONE* item 
- Writer : Write *MULTIPLE* items at once

But can we implements something clean working like this : 
- Reader : Read *MULTIPLE* item/line 
- Processor : Transform *MULTIPLE* item/line into *ONE* line
- Writer : Write *ONE* line

Comment: See the [AggregateItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/sample/domain/multiline/AggregateItemReader.html) - basically read 100 lines into a List and that List object passed to the processor.  The processor doe the calculation and provides the result object.  The writer still receives a List, but it's a List with 1 element (might depend on chunk size) containing the result object from the processor.